# Induction on summation inequality stuck on Induction step

Tags: induction, computer-science

working on a fairly simple induction problem, but stuck when decomposing the m+1^st summation and bringing in the I.H to show it holds.

I am bad with formatting so bare with me.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2} \leq 2 - \frac1n$$

Base Case:
Set $n = 1$ and show that the inequality holds

IH:
Assume for all $n = m$, $\sum_{k=1}^m \frac1{k^2} \leq 2 - \frac1m$  holds

I.S:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac1{k^2} \leq 2 - \frac1{m+1}$$

since we can decompose m+1 to m we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \frac1{k^2} + \frac1{m^2} \le 2 - \frac1m$$

then we can use I.H since we have $\sum_{k=1}^m \frac1{k^2} \le 2 - \frac1{m+1}$

so I am trying to show $2 - 1/(m+1) + 1/(m^2)$, but I am stuck here since I cannot manipulate the equation to come to the m+1st equation on the RHS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the inductive step you have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \le 2 - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}  \le 2 - \frac{1}{m+1}$$

The last inequality is true as:

$$\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \ge \frac{1}{m+1} \iff (m+1)^2 - m \ge m(m+1) \iff m^2 + m + 1 \ge m^2 + m$$

Comment: we cannot simplify to show that it is m+1, but the implication shows that this is true for the above inequality, am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @ZeroDayFracture I'm not sure I understand what is your question. From what I understood you are asking about reducing $-\frac 1m + \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$ to $\frac{-1}{m+1}$. It's enough to show that $-\frac 1m + \frac{1}{(m+1)^2} \le \frac{-1}{m+1}$, which would prove the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

i think it must be
$$\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}\le 2-\frac{1}{m+1}$$ and it must be
$$\le 2-\frac{1}{m}+ \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}\le 2-\frac{1}{m+1}$$

Comment: how can `2 - 1/m + 1/(m+1)^2 <= 2 - 1/(m+1)` ?

Comment: this is equivalent to $$m\le (m+1)^2-m(m+1)$$

Comment: simplifying we get $$m\le m+1$$ and this is true.